# PHP MySQL Update Set query with Multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I've tried this query with both commas and "AND" statements as pictured below. I get a syntax error

> Something went wrong.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'are available 24/7 by phone and email to answer any questions and to assist you '` at line 1

every time I try this query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE general
    SET bookabandheading = $_POST[bookabandheading 
    AND bookaband = $_POST[bookaband]
    AND contactus = $_POST[contactus]
    AND aboutuslisten = $_POST[aboutuslisten]
    AND contactusheading = $_POST[contactusheading]
    AND nightclubsheading = $_POST[nightclubsheading]
    AND acousticheading = $_POST[acousticheading]
    AND schoolsheading = $_POST[schoolsheading]
    AND privateheading = $_POST[privateheading]
    AND concertsheading = $_POST[concertsheading]
    AND festivalsheading = $_POST[festivalsheading]
    AND submissions = $_POST[submissions]
    AND interns = $_POST[interns]
    AND managementbio = $_POST[managementbio]
    AND latestnews = $_POST[latestnews]
    AND artistofthemonth = $_POST[artistofthemonth]
    AND artistofthemonthphoto = $_POST[artistofthemonthphoto]
    AND artistofthemonthid = $_POST[artistofthemonthid]
    AND listentoourartists = $_POST[listentoourartists]
    AND musicianswanted = $_POST[musicianswanted]
    AND aboutus = $_POST[aboutus]
    AND bshowcases = $_POST[bshowcases]
    AND bandavails = $_POST[bandavails]");
```

The query worked in a different database on another VPS, but I just migrated servers and it no longer works. Any help is greatly appeciated!

Comment: If you could paste here the exact error message, that would help solving the problem a lot.

Comment: Something went wrong.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'are available 24/7 by phone and email to answer any questions and to assist you ' at line 1

Comment: This error means, that one of the fields in $_POST contains the string `...are available 24/7...` and so on, and raw, unescaped, unquoted strings in sql queries are not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the main problem is that you missed the closing bracket after bookamandheading, still I would like to advise you to refactor this request for example like this:

```
$keys = array("bookabandheading", "bookaband", "contactus", "aboutuslisten",
              "contactusheading", "nightclubsheading", "acousticheading",
              "schoolsheading", "privateheading", "concertsheading",
              "festivalsheading", "submissions", "interns", "managementbio",
              "latestnews", "artistofthemonth", "artistofthemonthphoto",
              "artistofthemonthid", "listentoourartists", "musicianswanted",
              "aboutus", "bshowcases", "bandavails");
$set = array();
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $set[] = sprintf(" %s = '%s' ", $key, mysql_escape_string($_POST[$key]));
}
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE general SET " . implode(", ", $set));
```

It is much easier to maintain and also a bit more secure by escaping the input.

**Update:** add where statement example

```
$where = array();
$where[] = sprintf(" some_string = '%s' ", mysql_escape_string($some_string));
$where[] = sprintf(" some_integer = %d ", $some_integer);
$where = " WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $where);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE general SET " . implode(", ", $set) . " " . $where);
```

Comment: is it possible to add a where clause to this sort of statement?

Answer (score 1):

I see 3 things wrong with this:

- Raw POST data in your query - at the very least user mysql_real_escape_string
- The parameters look like strings so should have quotes around them
- There's no WHERE option, so you'll update every row in that table

Comment: I still can't get it to work when updated 2 or more fields after trying quotes around the strings.

Comment: I recommend using TEXT type instead of VARCHAR type for your MySQL database and combine it with textareas for your form instead of textboxes- this even keeps spaces in your data.

Comment: Somehow the keyword AND does not work for update statements, rather use a komma instead: UPDATE TableName SET column1='value' AND column2='value2' WHERE someColumn='some_value'; does not work.
Rather use: UPDATE tableName SET column1='value', column2='value2' WHERE someColumn='some_value';

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors:

- Syntax error. Change

  **$_POST[bookabandheading** to **$_POST[bookabandheading]**
- This is also incredibly prone to SQL injections. You should be using mysqli, but if you are set on mysql (which is deprecated as of 5.5.0), you should escape each $_POST variable using mysql_real_escape_string().
- Each $_POST variable needs to bee parameterized using quotes a well. So, an example:

  **$_POST['bookabandheading']** (do this for all $_POST variables)

Answer (score 0):

```
$_POST[bookabandheading
```

change to

```
$_POST[bookabandheading]
```